# Validate NSString for beginning with # symbol

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

How to check if an `NSString` contains the first letter as "#". I mean if the string has `#wiki` it has to accept. Actually I am trying to validate twitter account details.

Please let me know how I can validate the `NSString` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Costique answer is best solution, and also you can use like below

```
 NSString *str = @"#i123";
        if([str rangeOfString:@"#"].location==0)
        {
            NSLog(@"YES");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"NO");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

See [`NSString` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for details:

```
if ([myString hasPrefix: @"#"]) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this & check if first character is # or not :

```
NSString *firstLetter = [String substringToIndex:1];
if([firstLetter isEqualToString:@"#"])
  {
    NSLog(@"Valid");
  }
```

Comment: You should always check the string's `length` before sending `substringToIndex:` because the latter may throw `NSRangeException`.